# Why would a common Gate MOSFET (instead of a resistor) reduce noise in a TIA?

Tags: resistors, transimpedance, common-gate

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMlwPq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am reading a paper on TIA for optical receivers. On one of the improvements regarding the noise the writers replace the feedback resistor with a common gate MOSFET biased on the triode.

I can see how the MOSFET provides better flexibility regarding the value of feedback resistance (as it can be manipulated through Vg), but I can't tell why, as they say, it is used "in order to optimize the noise".

Comment: A circuit diagram may help., As may a reference to the paper. It may be that the MOSFET provides a degree of constant current action or have some other "law" which makes it suit in some way. | A bipolar transistor operated in that manner is used to create a log voltage amplifier  - I'd need to play (if only thought experiment wise) with a FET and TIA version to see if it made sense.

Comment: Can you refer (ideally link) to the paper? I feel there's some context missing. Perhaps this is in the context of large dynamic range, where a resistor big enough to prevent overload would impose a noise penalty, but a non-linear device gives the best of both worlds?